# Python - glob.glob doesn't find *.txt in specified filepath within Unix OS

Tags: python, unix, filepath, glob, sungridengine

I am converting some Python scripts I wrote in a Windows environment to run in Unix (Red Hat 5.4), and I'm having trouble converting the lines that deal with filepaths. In Windows, I usually read in all .txt files within a directory using something like:

```
pathtotxt = "C:\\Text Data\\EJC\\Philosophical Transactions 1665-1678\\*\\*.txt"
for file in glob.glob(pathtotxt):
```

It seems one can use the glob.glob() method in Unix as well, so I'm trying to implement this method to find all text files within a directory entitled "source" using the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import commands
import sys
import glob
import os

testout = open('testoutput.txt', 'w')
numbers = [1,2,3]
for number in numbers:
    testout.write(str(number + 1) + "\r\n")
testout.close

sourceout = open('sourceoutput.txt', 'w')
pathtosource = "/afs/crc.nd.edu/user/d/dduhaime/data/hill/source/*.txt"
for file in glob.glob(pathtosource):
    with open(file, 'r') as openfile:
        readfile = openfile.read()
        souceout.write (str(readfile))
sourceout.close
```

When I run this code, the testout.txt file comes out as expected, but the sourceout.txt file is empty. I thought the problem might be solved if I change the line

```
pathtosource = "/afs/crc.nd.edu/user/d/dduhaime/data/hill/source/*.txt"
```

to

```
pathtosource = "/source/*.txt"
```

and then run the code from the /hill directory, but that didn't resolve my problem. Do others know how I might be able to read in the text files in the source directory? I would be grateful for any insights others can offer.

EDIT: In case it is relevant, the /afs/ tree of directories referenced above is located on a remote server that I'm ssh-ing into via Putty. I'm also using a test.job file to qsub the Python script above. (This is all to prepare myself to submit jobs on the SGE cluster system.) The test.job script looks like:

```
#!/bin/csh
#$ -M dduhaime@nd.edu
#$ -m abe
#$ -r y
#$ -o tmp.out
#$ -e tmp.err
module load python/2.7.3
echo "Start - `date`"
python tmp.py 
echo "Finish - `date`"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it! I had misspelled the output command. I wrote

```
souceout.write (str(readfile))
```

instead of

```
sourceout.write (str(readfile))
```

What a dunce. I also added a newline bit to the line:

```
sourceout.write (str(readfile) + "\r\n")
```

and it works fine. I think it's time for a new IDE!

Comment: I fixed that also, but I thought it is an error on my side :). Nice to hear that it works.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't really closed the file. The function `testout.close()` isn't called, because you have forgotten the parentheses. The same is for `sourceout.close()`

```
testout.close
...
sourceout.close
```

Has to be:

```
testout.close()
...
sourceout.close()
```

If the program finishes all files are automatically closed so it is only important if you reopen the file.
Even better (the pythonic version) would be to use the `with` statement. Instead of this:

```
testout = open('testoutput.txt', 'w')
numbers = [1,2,3]
for number in numbers:
    testout.write(str(number + 1) + "\r\n")
testout.close()
```

you would write this:

```
with open('testoutput.txt', 'w') as testout:
    numbers = [1,2,3]
    for number in numbers:
        testout.write(str(number + 1) + "\r\n")
```

In this case the file will be automatically closed even when an error occurs.

Comment: I added the parentheses after the `close()` lines, but the sourceoutput.txt file is still coming out blank...

Comment: Try to use `"./"` as path and start the program in the folder where the files are located.

Comment: I tried changing the glob.glob line to `for file in glob.glob('./*.txt'):` but am still not getting any output. I added some more information in the question above (the information about the .job file I'm using to submit the .py script) in case that's relevant

Comment: It's a bit strange, because it worked for me. Could you test it locally, to see if something with the other things (server, connection, ...) is not correct.